# create new element on xajax

Tags: php, javascript, xajax

hi everyone it's my again. maybe its a stupid question but i can do it :>

I need to create a div object inside my xajax function. I do so

```
$response->create("parent id","The name of the new element","new id");
```

So far SO good. Next, i assign a property to my new object like this

```
$response->assign("new id","style.display","block")
```

again so far so good. My problem is when wanting to create a attribute. This is my code

```
$response->assign("new id","class","name of my class");
```

in html is something like `<div id="p-new id" class="name of my class">`

but i can't do this. Any suggestions are very good

Thanks.

Comment: Is the above example PHP or JS code? Could be both…

Comment: this instructions are made in php inside my xajax function

Answer (score 1):

Remember that 
`->assign(*id*, *prop*, *value*)` is translated into
`document.getElementById(*id*).*prop* = *value*;`

Because *class* is a reserved word in Javascript, the class attribute is handled by the property `className`.

So `$response->assign("new id","className","name of my class");`
will work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create whole object in one line like:

```
$response->assign("parent-id","innerHTML","<div id='p-new id' class='name of my class'>");
```

or if you can't change parent-id innerHTML create:
firstly new-id div:

```
$response->create("parent-id","The name of the new element","new-id");
```

and then assign it's innerHTML new div:

```
$response->assign("parent-id","innerHTML","<div class='name of my class'></div>");
```

Unfortunatelly you will get structure

```
<div id="p-new id"> <class="name of my class"></div> </div>
```

not as you want

```
<div id="p-new id" class="name of my class"></div>
```

But you can adjust this idea to your needs and create sth like

```
<div id="outer-sth"><div id="p-new id" class="name of my class"></div></div>
```

Which I belive is close enough to what you are asking.